# No scroll for first list item

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I'd like a horizontal list as Google Play has, but I need first item to be static, so scrolling must start from second one like in this pic:
[image]

So is that even possible? I don't want to create a static view then put a list at baseline of this item.

Comment: Can you put your codes?

Comment: how about warping your item and horizontal list inside horizontal LinearLayout?

Comment: How about list header ?

Comment: @shadygoneinsane list header scrolls with list

Comment: Creating a static view and adding a list beside it, seems to be the easiest solution though.

Comment: use first item as seperate view in xml like below:

<CardView/>
<RecyclerView/>